# Copy-Item over remote network path using WinRS throws UnauthorisedAccessException

Tags: powershell, winrs

```
$_sourcepath = '\\servername\DriveLetter$\folder\file.zip'
$_destinationPath = 'D:\Temp\file.zip'
Copy-Item -Path $_sourcepath -Destination $_destinationPath;
```

My PowerShell script is run using WinRS in MSBuilds. It throws UnauthorisedAccessException but works fine when running on the local server.

Now I'm using 
`$Username = Domain\username";
   $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
   $session = new-pssession -computername 'serverName' -credential $cred 
 Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {copy-Item -Path $($args[0])  -destination $($args[1])} -argumentlist $_sourcepath,$_destinationPath ;`

and im still getting Unauthorized AccessException.

Comment: Sounds like a [2nd hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/).

Comment: even using pssession does not work for me.